# Vim global replace (line)

Tags: vim

The "global" option does not work as expected (this seems to have changed only recently, but I'm not able to track down the reason for the difference yet).

Given the line:

*aba*

I issue the command:

*:s/a//g*

I expect the result to be:

*b*

However, the resulting line is:

*ba*

What have I missed?

Comment: works for me.  could there be something funny in your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Yes, gdefault was set. I'll have to go back in version control to remind myself when I changed it. I feel pretty foolish for having forgotten about this! o_O

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You most likely have `gdefault` set in your `.vimrc`.

From `:help gdefault`:

```
When on, the ":substitute" flag 'g' is default on.  This means that
all matches in a line are substituted instead of one.  When a 'g' flag
is given to a ":substitute" command, this will toggle the substitution
of all or one match.
```

If you are not setting this in your config you can see where it is set by issuing `:verbose set gdefault?`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the reminder! Now if I can just remember why I set gdefault in the first place... :o)

Answer (score 2):

If the input and the command are *exactly* as you give them, I see no reason for this behaviour.

My money is on the second "a" not being what you think it is. For example, it could be the [Cyrillic "a", i.e. "а" (U+0430)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/430/index.htm). On my screen the two are indistinguishable.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight. However, they were indeed the same 'a'. I typed them! :o)